# Android : see full url when you make a POST request to a server

Tags: android, json, url, post

here's my problem :
I have a function that make a post request to a server, I tested it on http://hmkcode.appspot.com/post-json/index.html and it seems to work just fine. But when I try it on my own server that should receive the specific post request (json) and give me back some json, it won't send me anything. My problem must be what I send but I can't find the error, so can you check the full URL when you POST (with the debbuger for example) ? Exemple : "http://example.com/receive/data?{"id"=12,"name"="example"}" .   Here is my code :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strJson ) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(SERVER);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(strJson[0]);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="NO HTTP_OK : " + responseCode;
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        response = "malformedURL" + e.toString();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        response = "Protocol" + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        response = "IOException" + e.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "Exception" + e.toString();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: `url.toString()`?

Comment: What about `Log.d("debugurl",url.toString());`?

Comment: Log.e("url","...."+url.tostring()); then check your log.

Comment: @Denny no when I do url.toString() it show me "http://example.com/receive/data" but not the post request I made

Comment: You could use Volley to send POST requests: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: @Denny why not use it to improve my code but I'd still have the same problem : the server see my request but when he analyse it, he don't accept it (probably because my json is wrong). So I want to see my full url to check what I send exactly

Comment: `POST (with the debbuger for example) ? Exemple : "http://example.com/receive/data?{"id"=12,"name"="example"}" ` That is not a POST request. That is a GET request. And a bad one. Only for a GET request there is a query string(after the ?). You will POST to full url: `"http://example.com/receive/data"`. And what you post is NOT in the url. If you want to see what you post then print strJson[0].

Comment: `writer.close();
        os.close();` Remove those statements.

Comment: `response+=line;` That should be  `response+=line + "\n";`

Comment: You should look at your server for what is received. The simplest to do is just echo back what you received. What kind of server? In own hands?

Comment: @greenapps I did as you said it still doesn't work, I really don't think my request is the problem as it seems to works on a different server. And I have the server in localhost but when I try to access it with 10.0.2.2 it answer me with error 400, so I test my code on the real server (one that I can't modify or touch)

Comment: So you are using an emulator? And what is the difference between your locathost server and a real server? What does 400 mean? And what kind of script you use?

Comment: @greenapps Normally there is no difference in the real server and the localhost, but my code doesn't work with the localhost. And error 400 mean "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."

Comment: `And what kind of script you use?`. If you want help then you should tell more about your server. I think you can change the scripts for your local server?

Comment: @greenapps I don't know and can't know anything about the server :/ the only thing I know is that it work on a real server and not on the local server (that is the same)

Comment: If it is on a local server, your pc. Then you have acces. And you should exactly know what kind of server it is. Why not? Who installed the server? You i think. Try a real device while connecting to local server.

Comment: @greenapps I kind of have access to it but I don't really understand the code, even more if it's to check why I have an error 400, it's wasn't me who created it and I can't ask the one who did it to explain me :/ if the answer needs me to modify the server, I can't do it, only have the rights to modify android code

Comment: The localhost pc is the same pc as where your emulator is running on i hope. If not you should have told us. And if it is the same pc i see no reason why you have no access to server code or scripts. And if you cannot modify it you can read it. And tell us what kind of server you use.

Comment: `I don't really understand the code,` Then show us.

Comment: @greenapps Yes the localhost is on my PC, but I can't answer questions about server, really sorry, I don't know a thing about them. If the problem is on the server side, it's pointless to continue this chat. Thanks you for trying to help men, and sorry to not being able to answer your questions ^^',

Comment: @greenapps I "received permission" to touch a bit the server, it is IIS. ADV with IIS seems special so it's normal that 10.0.2.2 doesn't work from what I understood

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
InputStream inputStream; 
HttpURLConnection urlConnection; 
byte[] outputBytes;

public class WebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            outputBytes = query.getBytes("UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(outputBytes);
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            ResponseData = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return ResponseData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);


    }

    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Pass your parameters in json string format like this

```
JSONObject() params = new JSONObject();
params.put("key","your parameter");
params.put("key","your parameter");

query=params.toString();
```